# How to add <<input>> to this puml code like in the attach image?

Tags: plantuml, puml

[image]

I added a sketch of what I want

I want to add `<<input>>` to this code
I added **:HW type\n detected; <>** but I don't know how to attach it with 'HW type detected' element

```
@startuml Type Initialization

start
:Read default type\n ;
:HW type detected;
if (Compare types) is (matches) then
:Continue;

stop
else (doesn't match)
:Store detected\n type ;
end

:HW type\n detected; <<input>>
@enduml
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
@startuml Type Initialization

start
:Read default type\n ;
:HW type detected<
if (Compare types) is (matches) then
:Continue;

stop
else (doesn't match)
:Store detected\n type ;
end

@enduml
```

[image: UML Activity]

Using the new syntax of `:HW type detected; <<input>>` gives the same effect.

```
@startuml Type Initialization

start
:Read default type\n ;
:HW type detected; <<input>>
if (Compare types) is (matches) then
:Continue;

stop
else (doesn't match)
:Store detected\n type ;
end

:HW type\n detected; <<input>>
@enduml
```

I am testing with the online tool at http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000

Comment: No, please see the image attached. i want additional << input>> to connect with another element. (see the red arrow)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want. Do you want 2 'HW Type Detected' elements? Can you sketch out what you want?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 'HW type detected' elements and I want to connect them as in the sketch attached

Answer (score 0):

The input box you want to use is part of the [SDL](https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta#7420c7766a064a28).
It has a particular meaning -- it's not really part of just drawing a flow chart, at least not in the context of PlantUML.

Input is used to show a match of a particular type of message that is received (input).

Here's a possible solution to your question, assuming the step of *Read default type* is where you allow input. I added another `input` box, *Other type detected*, to show how it could work in the context of `split` (alternate flows, depending on the input received).

```
@startuml Type Initialization

start
:Read default type\n ;
split
:HW type detected; <<input>>
if (Compare types) is (matches) then
  :Continue;
else (doesn't match)
  :Store detected\n type ;
end if
split again
:other type\n detected; <<input>>
end split
stop
@enduml
```

[image: PlantUML SDL diagram with Inputs]

Comment: Thank you but it's not what I want. I want to add this input like in my sketch so I can do the type comparison.